# Django-Admin: CharField as TextArea

Tags: django, django-admin

I have

```
class Cab(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField( max_length=20 )
    descr = models.CharField( max_length=2000 )

class Cab_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering     = ('name',)
    list_display = ('name','descr', )
    # what to write here to make descr using TextArea?

admin.site.register( Cab, Cab_Admin )
```

how to assign TextArea widget to 'descr' field in admin interface?

**upd:**
In **Admin** interface only!

Good idea to use ModelForm.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You will have to create a `forms.ModelForm` that will describe how you want the `descr` field to be displayed, and then tell `admin.ModelAdmin` to use that form. For example:

```
from django import forms
class CabModelForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    descr = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )
    class Meta:
        model = Cab

class Cab_Admin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    form = CabModelForm
```

The `form` attribute of `admin.ModelAdmin` is documented in the official Django documentation. Here is [one place to look at](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).

Comment: For simply replacing a form widget, you don't have to create your own entire form. You can just override `formfield_for_dbfield` on your `ModelAdmin`, see my answer below.

Comment: This gives `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited`

Comment: Starting from Django 1.7 you need to add also `fields = '__all__'` under `class Meta:`.

Comment: You don't need to create the form yourself, you can override `get_form` method. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50521580/52499).

Comment: beeter approach is to use Meta
class Meta:
        model = Message
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the only serious answer that may be found for this question. Just note that the Meta of the Form class must contain a declaration of "fields", as already said here.

Answer (score 68):

For this case, the best option is probably just to use a TextField instead of CharField in your model.  You can also override the `formfield_for_dbfield` method of your `ModelAdmin` class:

```
class CabAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        formfield = super(CabAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'descr':
            formfield.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs=formfield.widget.attrs)
        return formfield
```

Comment: is there any downside in this compared to the selected answer? this looks cleaner to implement as we don't need to create a new ModelForm...

Comment: replaced `formfield.widget = forms.Textarea()` with `formfield.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs=formfield.widget.attrs)` to keep all attributes automatically generated for the TextField, Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why the other answer is accepted over this one; I think if all you're doing is replacing a widget this is simpler. But either will work fine.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. The super() invocation seems a bit verbose though, is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @rjh In py3 you can eliminate everything inside the parens and just use `super()`. Otherwise no.

Comment: @CarlMeyer : is there any way I can keep all attributes of Charfield in textarea plus new attributes like cols and rows.

Comment: You should also add: `admin.site.register(Cab, CabAdmin)` after the class definition

Comment: Is `formfield_for_dbfield` documented?

Comment: Using a `TextField` instead of a `CharField` on the model is a database-level change, and may have unintended consequences.  There's a reason they're separate fields.  Overriding the widget is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 36):

Ayaz has pretty much spot on, except for a slight change(?!):

```
class MessageAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }

class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MessageAdminForm
admin.site.register(Message, MessageAdmin)
```

So, you don't need to redefine a field in the ModelForm to change it's widget, just set the widgets dict in Meta.

Comment: This does retain more "automatic" properties than Ayaz's answer, but any tip on how to keep the field length validation as well?

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to create the form class yourself:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widgets'] = {'descr': forms.Textarea}
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

See [ModelAdmin.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form).

Answer (score 14):

You can subclass your own field with needed `formfield` method:

```
class CharFieldWithTextarea(models.CharField):

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({"widget": forms.Textarea})
        return super(CharFieldWithTextarea, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

This will take affect on all generated forms.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to change the Textarea on admin.py, this is the solution that worked for me:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea

from books.models import Book

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100}))
    class Meta:
        model = Book

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BookForm

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

If you are using a MySQL DB, your column length will usually be autoset to 250 characters, so you will want to run an ALTER TABLE to change the length in you MySQL DB, so that you can take advantage of the new larger Textarea that you have in you Admin Django site.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a `models.CharField`, use a `models.TextField` for `descr`.

Comment: Unfortunately, max_length= is totally ignored by Django on a TextField, so when you need field length validation (such as letting secretaries enter event summaries) the only way to get it is to use a CharField. But a CharField is way to short to type 300 chars into. Hence the ayaz solution.

Comment: This isn't a good answer because it changes the database. The point of changing the widget is to change how the field is displayed, not to change the database schema

Comment: It's a great answer for someone (like me) who is learning how to use Django and would have set up the database differently in the first place if I'd known better.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `models.TextField` for this purpose:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    field2 = models.TextField(max_length=1024*2)   # Will be rendered as textarea
```

Comment: This will change DB structure so be carefull

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to expand on Carl Meyer's answer, which works perfectly till this date.

I always use `TextField` instead of `CharField` (with or without choices) and impose character limits on UI/API side rather than at DB level. To make this work dynamically:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin


class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Base admin capable of forcing widget conversion
    """
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        formfield = super(BaseAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(
            db_field, **kwargs)

        display_as_charfield = getattr(self, 'display_as_charfield', [])
        display_as_choicefield = getattr(self, 'display_as_choicefield', [])

        if db_field.name in display_as_charfield:
            formfield.widget = forms.TextInput(attrs=formfield.widget.attrs)
        elif db_field.name in display_as_choicefield:
            formfield.widget = forms.Select(choices=formfield.choices,
                                            attrs=formfield.widget.attrs)

        return formfield
```

I have a model name `Post` where `title`, `slug` & `state` are `TextField`s and `state` has choices. The admin definition looks like:

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'title', 'author', 'org', 'state', 'created',)
    search_fields = [
        'title',
        'author__username',
    ]
    display_as_charfield = ['title', 'slug']
    display_as_choicefield = ['state']
```

Thought others looking for answers might find this useful.

Comment: Is this `formfield_for_dbfield` documented?