# Resize fields in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Django tends to fill up horizontal space when adding or editing entries on the admin, but, in some cases, is a real waste of space, when, i.e., editing a date field, 8 characters wide, or a CharField, also 6 or 8 chars wide, and then the edit box goes up to 15 or 20 chars.

How can I tell the admin how wide a textbox should be, or the height of a TextField edit box?

Comment: Obviously, you forgot to do that in this case.  More than two years later. =)

Comment: Project got ditched and I didn't got to see code for a while. I may begin a new project next month, so maybe I'll se this again :D

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You should use [ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).

It is quite easy - in `admin.py`, define:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':40})},
    }

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for without having to make some ridiculous template customizations. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this will not work if `filter_horizontal` or `filter_vertical` is set for the corresponding fields in YourModelAdmin. I've spent some time to figure this out.

Comment: Is there any awy to this in a form? I did not find a way to set the attrs attribute for all Textareas.

Comment: I used only `models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':4})}` but width became smaller too.

Comment: It is hard to have them the same size apparently.

Comment: Standing at 2020, how can I change width of corresponding label?

Answer (score 46):

**To change the width for a specific field.**

Made via [ModelAdmin.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form):

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['myfield'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 45em;'
        return form
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer, since it allows for changing individual fields without having to create a new form.

Answer (score 45):

You can set arbitrary HTML attributes on a widget using its ["attrs" property](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs).

You can do this in the Django admin using formfield_for_dbfield:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    field = super(ContentAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name == 'somefield':
      field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'someclass ' + field.widget.attrs.get('class', '')
    return field
```

or with a custom Widget subclass and the [formfield_overrides dictionary](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides):

```
class DifferentlySizedTextarea(forms.Textarea):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    attrs = kwargs.setdefault('attrs', {})
    attrs.setdefault('cols', 80)
    attrs.setdefault('rows', 5)
    super(DifferentlySizedTextarea, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  formfield_overrides = { models.TextField: {'widget': DifferentlySizedTextarea}}
```

Answer (score 24):

A quick and dirty option is to simply provide a custom template for the model in question.

If you create a template named `admin/<app label>/<class name>/change_form.html` then the admin will use that template instead of the default. That is, if you've got a model named `Person` in an app named `people`, you'd create a template named `admin/people/person/change_form.html`.

All the admin templates have an `extrahead` block you can override to place stuff in the `<head>`, and the final piece of the puzzle is the fact that every field has an HTML id of `id_<field-name>`.

So, you could put something like the following in your template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <style type="text/css">
    #id_my_field { width: 100px; }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This and the answer by alanjds are very helpful for changing the layout in the admin interface on a per-field basis, rather than a per-field-type basis.

Comment: Still works in Django 4.2a1!

Comment: Works also for `change_list.html` in case you want to change the `list_view` as well

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the attributes on a per-field instance, you can add the "attrs" property directly in to your form entries.

for example:

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title:', max_length=128)
    body = forms.CharField(label='Post:', max_length=2000, 
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'5', 'cols': '5'}))

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'body')
```

The "attrs" property basically passes along the HTML markup that will adjust the form field.  Each entry is a tuple of the attribute you would like to override and the value you would like to override it with.  You can enter as many attributes as you like as long as you separate each tuple with a comma.

Comment: IMO the best way to modify only a single field and not all TextInput-widgets at once (like the accepted answer does)

Answer (score 9):

You can always set your fields sizes in a custom stylesheet and tell Django to use that for your ModelAdmin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {"all": ("my_stylesheet.css",)}
```

Comment: best answer! no fiddling with formfields and attributes (and possible side effects), just a css file, that can - with existing ids/classes in django admin forms - easily target only some, or even all fields. big up!

Answer (score 8):

The best way I found is something like this:

```
class NotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(NotificationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs['cols'] = 80
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 15
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['size'] = 50
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
```

Its much better for ModelForm than overriding fields with different widgets, as it preserves `name` and `help_text` attributes and also default values of model fields, so you don't have to copy them to your form.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with TextField.  I'm using Django 1.0.2 and wanted to change the default value for 'rows' in the associated textarea.  formfield_overrides doesn't exist in this version.  Overriding formfield_for_dbfield worked but I had to do it for each of my ModelAdmin subclasses or it would result in a recursion error.  Eventually, I found that adding the code below to models.py works:

```
from django.forms import Textarea

class MyTextField(models.TextField):
#A more reasonably sized textarea                                                                                                            
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
         kwargs.update(
            {"widget": Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':80})}
         )
         return super(MyTextField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Then use MyTextField instead of TextField when defining your models. I adapted it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430592/djang-admin-charfield-as-textarea/430652#430652) to a similar question.

Answer (score 5):

It's well described in [Django FAQ](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewformsHOWTO#Q:HowdoIchangetheattributesforawidgetonafieldinmymodel.):

**Q:** How do I change the attributes for a widget on a field in my model?

**A:** Override the formfield_for_dbfield in the ModelAdmin/StackedInline/TabularInline class

```
class MyOtherModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyOtherModel
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        # This method will turn all TextFields into giant TextFields
        if isinstance(db_field, models.TextField):
            return forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 130, 'rows':30, 'class': 'docx'}))
        return super(MyOtherModelInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: When I use this technique the help text won't appear, and if it's a TabularInline, the column header becomes 'None'.

Comment: This is not a good approach, as you're wiping out all the other settings in the CharField. For example, by default, it'll intelligently detect whether or not the form field should be required, but this code destroys that. You should instead set the widget on the value returned by your super() call.

Answer (score 2):

for 1.6, using forms I had to specify the attributes of the textarea inside the charfield:

```
test1 = forms.CharField(max_length=400, widget=forms.Textarea( attrs={'rows':'2', 'cols': '10'}),  initial='', help_text=helptexts.helptxt['test'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple, yet flexible solution. Use a custom form to override some widgets.

```py
# models.py
class Elephant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.IntegerField()

# forms.py
class ElephantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'age': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 3}),
        }

# admin.py
@admin.register(Elephant)
class ElephantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ElephantForm
```

The widgets given in `ElephantForm` will replace the default ones. The key is the string representation of the field. Fields not specified in the form will use the default widget.

Note that although `age` is an `IntegerField` we can use the `TextInput` widget, because unlike the `NumberInput`, `TextInput` accepts the `size` attribute.

This solution is described [in this article](http://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2011/08/31/django-admin-resizing-form-fields-for-tabularinline/).

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as msdin but with TextInput instead of TextArea:

```
from django.forms import TextInput

class ShortTextField(models.TextField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
         kwargs.update(
            {"widget": TextInput(attrs={'size': 10})}
         )
         return super(ShortTextField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a ForeignKey field that involves choices/options/a dropdown menu, you can override `formfield_for_foreignkey` in the Admin instance:

```
class YourNewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'your_fk_field':
            """ For your FK field of choice, override the dropdown style """
            kwargs["widget"] = django.forms.widgets.Select(attrs={
                'style': 'width: 250px;'
            })

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

More information on this pattern [here](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filter_fk_dropdown.html) and [here](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/fk_display.html).

Answer (score 0):

For example, there is **`Product` model** below:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField() 
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, using [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) or [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form) below.

`formfield_overrides`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.db import models
from django import forms

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = { # Here
        models.CharField: {
            'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'})
        },
        models.TextField: {
            'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'50'})
        },
        models.DecimalField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
        models.PositiveSmallIntegerField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
    }
```

`form`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'50'}),
            'price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width:50ch'
            }),
            'quantity' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width:50ch'
            })
        }

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm # Here
```

`form`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'})
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'50'})
    )
    price = forms.DecimalField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:50ch'})
    )
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:50ch'})
    )

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm # Here
```

You can change **the size of the fields** in **"Add" and "Change" pages** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

In addition, in this case of only `formfield_overrides`, you can change **the size of the fields** in **"Change List" page** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.db import models
from django import forms

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'price', 'quantity')
    list_editable = ('name',) # Here
    list_display_links = ('description',)

    formfield_overrides = { # Here
        models.CharField: {
            'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'})
        },
        models.TextField: {
            'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'1', 'cols':'50'})
        },
        models.DecimalField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
        models.PositiveSmallIntegerField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

And one more example too :

```
class SecenekInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Secenek
   # classes = ['collapse']
   def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
       field = super(SecenekInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
       if db_field.name == 'harf':
           field.widget = TextInput(attrs={'size':2})
       return field
   formfield_overrides = {
       models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2})},
   }
   extra = 2
```

If you want to edit only a specific fields size, you can use this.