# Django displaying CharField as TextField in forms error

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a a field called text which is a CharField work like an textfield because I can't use textfield in forms so What I did was I enlarged the charfield 
using CSS . The problem is , when I type a sentence . The sentence is display not from top to bottom like textfield but in the middle of box like a straight line. How do I make this Charfield work extactly like textfield

[image]
 models.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.Textfield(max_length=100)
```

My forms.py

```
class HouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(required=False, )

    class Meta:
         model = House
         fields = ('name', 'description',)
```

my views.py

```
def House(request):
     form = houseForm()
     return render(request,'house.html',{'form':form})
```

template

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.name}}
{{form.text}}
{{form.description}}
<input type = "submit" value="save" id="box2"/>
</form>
```

My CSS

```
#id_text {
    width: 230px;
    height: 80px;
    color:#9B5A3C;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    position:absolute;
    left:700px;
    top: 260px;
}
```

Comment: And you can't use a textarea widget? `text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)`

Comment: @limelights , oh man . Your correct . I was swimming around that answers at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430592/django-admin-charfield-as-textarea but I thought it was specify for admin template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your use case use a TextArea widget

```
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

if you wanna specify some attributes for the widget you can do this in your form which think is pretty nice.

```
class HouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = House
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5, 'cols':10}), #this is changeble.
        }
```

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

Comment: Np, glad I could help, if it helped you don't forget to accept, more rep for me AND you! :)

Comment: what about specifying an ID?             'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'id':'hello'}),

Comment: Normally widgets in forms comes with their own autogenerated id, so I wouldn't mess with it but you can add classes as you choose `'class' : 'yournewclasshere'`