# How to correctly pre-populate textarea in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this rather annoying problem:

In the template I have

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.aboutme.errors }}
    <label for="aboutme">About Me:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="aboutme" value="{{form.aboutme}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

It renders the textarea pre-populated but with the value but prints a redundant `">` at the end of the box.

The raw html looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="aboutme" value="<p><textarea cols=" 40"="" name="aboutme">My Name is Django</textarea>
```

Which obviously has an unintnded `textarea` tag inserted within.

the field is:

```
 aboutme=models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('About Me'))
```

And there is no specia widget used for it in its respective ModelForm class.

So really confused how to correctly render this field?

Answer (score 5):

The textarea html tag has no value attribute. The right syntax is:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="aboutme">{{ form.aboutme.value }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/) about widgets.

In this situation you could go with following. Try to get the value from the field:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="aboutme" value="{{form.aboutme.value}}"></textarea>
```

If it won't work, using article from link above or [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430592/django-admin-charfield-as-textarea) add widget to CharField of your form and then simply use:

```
{{ form.aboutme }}
```

As I see you've done it and Django successfuly render `<textarea>` with `<p>` tags and populated value. You could try to add more cutomization to widget.

Comment: Well, using `value="{{form.aboutme.value  }}` removes the extra `">` but caused the form to not be saved. Adding `aboutme = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )` does not remove the extra `">`  issue.

Comment: @Paulrx , If you use form widget as shown in another answer here or in my linkm then you should replace your html textarea with `{{ form.aboutme }}`. If you're going to stuck with your html, then you should add `name="aboutme"` to the html, so you will be able to save I think. Also, leave another comment next time if you found issues, because I wasn't notify about edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
aboutme = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 10, 'cols': 40}))

<div class="form-group">
       <label for="aboutme">About Me:</label>
       {{ form.aboutme.errors }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works in latest versions. 
{{form.aboutme}}

Answer (score 0):

While you create an instance of the form in view.py, you can set their initial value by the format below

```
form = SampleForm()
# CharField
form.fields['title'].initial = name
# TextArea
form.fields['text'].initial = entry
```

Form class where title is a Textinput and text is a Textarea set through Widgets in django forms

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title', widget=forms.TextInput())
    text =  forms.CharField(label='Content', widget=forms.Textarea())
```

HTML

```
<form action = '' method = 'post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```