# Django display a model property in admin as a TextField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model (Candidate) with a property (key) which return a big string.

I register this model in admin.py and add the field with:

```
class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['key']
```

But the field is displayed  as a CharField. How to show it in a TextField widget ?

Comment: what is date of your key field. It should be TextField.

Comment: key is a @property function in the model Candidate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430592/django-admin-charfield-as-textarea

Comment: Does not work, the text is still on one line.