# How to keep empty lines in a textarea in Django admin UI?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a field on an object, and I render it with a textarea in the Django (3.2) admin UI using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431412), something like:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    some_text = prompt = db.CharField(max_length=10000)

# ..

class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'some_text')

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        """Use Textarea for some_text.

        See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/431412."""
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'some_text':
            formfield.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 10, 'cols': 80})
        return formfield
```

When I edit in the Django admin UI, if I add empty lines (hitting enter several times), when I save, they all are gone.  So, while editing, empty lines:

[image: while editing]

But after it's saved, no newlines:

[image: after editing]

How do I get the Django admin UI to keep the empty lines (as newlines)?

If I have non-empty lines, it keeps all the newlines.

While editing:

[image]

After editing (dumped out to a file), with newlines:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [**`strip=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip) to disable stripping leading and trailing space:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name == 'some_text':
        formfield.strip = False
        formfield.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 10, 'cols': 80})
    return formfield
```

Comment: You are a crazy genius!

Comment: I did not realize strip=True by default, but that is confirmed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField